# My 99 Aurora oldsmobile overheating

Tags: overheating, oldsmobile, aurora

I just got a water pump put on my Aurora old mobile 99 and the heat keep going up and down. What could it be?

Comment: sounds like the system is not fully bled.  It could also still have a leak somewhere.  Have you been checking and topping off the coolant?

Answer (score 1):

A water pump is only one component of an engine cooling system.  You could have a partially clogged radiator, a thermostat that's not opening and closing properly, an air pocket in the system caused by the removal and replacement of the water pump.  Recommend getting someone who knows cooling systems to check it out for you.